# Convinient way to implement user roles in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Thanks for reading!

I'm currently working on my new app and searching for the best way to implement next feature

By scenario I need to implement "As a user a have role in the location"

## WHAT I HAVE DONE:

Scenario:
When user adds new location to the profile
one of the requred fields is "role". That could be "guest", "manager" or "seller". What's the best way to accomplish his in the model side?

I accomplished this with has_many_through assosiation

CONTROLLER:

```
def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    @location.profiles << current_user.profile
    #set user role
    current_user.profile.profile_location_throughs.where(location_id: location.id).set_role(params[:location][:role])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        ....
      end
    end
end
```

MODELS:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base do
  has_many :profile_location_throughs
  has_many :locations, through: :profile_location_throughs
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base do
  has_many :profile_location_throughs
  has_many :locations, through: :profile_location_throughs
end

class ProfileLocationThrough < ActiveRecord::Base
  # with boolean fields: manager, seller, guest

  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :profile

  def set_role(role)
    case role
      when "guest"
        self.guest = true
      when "seller"
        self.seller = true
      when "manager"
        self.manager = true
    end
  end

end
```

=====

QUESTION:
Could you suggest more beatiful way to implement his feature?

Comment: Can user have different roles in different locations? If yes, it is correct to manage it through associations. But, instead of just keeping the role name in each record of through table. Make a `roles` table and respective `Role` model and add an association to it in through table.

Comment: I see you have 3 different fields, one for each role. See, that may be bad because you will have to add new field to the model whenever a new role is defined. Instead you should keep single field `role` and save "guest", "manager" or "seller" in it.

Comment: Yes. In one locations it could be "seller", in other "guest" and so on

Comment: Please check my first comment. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do role based authorization.

The simplest way is by adding a [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to the users themselves:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:guest, :seller, :manager]
end
```

This is pretty limited though as it only allows "global" roles. 
If you want resource scoped roles you need a join table.

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :locations, through: :roles

  def has_role?(role, location = nil)
    self.roles.exists?( { name: role, location: location}.compact )
  end

  def add_role(role, location)
    self.roles.create!( { name: role, location: location } )
  end
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :profiles, through: :roles
end
```

In this example we are simply using a string for the `roles.name` column. You could also use an enum if the kinds of roles are limited. If you want to use the same Role model (no pun intended) to scope roles on different kinds of resources you can use a [polymorphic `belongs_to` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
  has_many :profiles, through: :roles
end

class OtherThing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
  has_many :profiles, through: :roles
end
```

Note that roles are just one part of an authentication solution. You would combine this with a authorization lib such as  [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which defines the rules about what role gets to do what and enforces those rules.

- [Rolify - Role management library with resource scoping](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)